# Display login / logout links in pyrocms?

Tags: authentication, logout, pyrocms

Hope you all people are enjoying your good health!

I am newbie to PyroCMS and I am facing issue with displaying Login and Logout links on the basis of User session. I tried hard to google to get help about this but could find proper help.

```
{ if'{session:data name="user_id" != "" }'}
      <li><a href="{{url:base}}users/logout">logout</a></li>
{/else}
      <li><a href="{{url:base}}users/login">log in</a></li>
{/if}
```

It is not working. Please help me to fix this issue!

Thank You.

Comment: You were close but that is a mixture of old (1.x) and new (2.x) syntax. The question has been answered correctly below, so could you accept it? :)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

PyroCMS has a tag specifically for checking if a user is already logged in. Try something like this:

```
{{ if user:logged_in }}
  <a href="{{ url:site uri='users/logout' }}">Logout</a>
{{ else }}
  <a href="{{ url:site uri='users/login' }}">Login</a>
{{ endif }}
```

Comment: Yep - see the [User plugin docs](http://docs.pyrocms.com/2.1/manual/index.php/modules-and-tags/tag-reference/user) - there's also a `{{ user:not_logged_in }}` method if you want to test specifically for that without using an *else*  statement.